# how to reload template in ng-include angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to reload template which I have included in page using ng-include

```
<div ng-include="exercise_tpl.url"></div>
```

I am able to do this by loading blank template and the again loading previous template like this

```
$scope.exercise_tpl.url = 'partials/blank.html';
        $('body').trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.exercise_tpl.url = 'partials/memory.html';
            $('body').trigger('click');
        }, 300);
```

I want to know right way of reloading template in Angularjs. Please help.

Comment: `$('body').trigger('click');` what is that?

Comment: I used trigger event to refresh page content. similar to $digest

Answer (score -1):

Templates are cached, if a user does not have the permissions to be in a page, then this check should be done before it reaches the controller or after, within the controller, but not on the template retrieval

If this is the way you want to follow, then you need to remove the template from the $templateCache before you call reload, something like:

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$route.reload();
```

Comment: Good answer, but the OP doesn't use routes.

Comment: Yes, im not using routes. This is just simple ng-include